# Is there a specific term and/or jocose name for a building resembling a motorcycle cylinder head?

Tags: single-word-requests

A cylinder head (with the cooling fins) looks like this:

[image]

There's a bunch of buildings that look like that in this image of downtown Houston:

[image]

Is there a specific name and/or term for those?

Comment: I don't see any buildings that look like that

Comment: *tiered* comes to mind although it is *'typically one of a series of rows placed one above the other and successively receding or diminishing in size'*. That describes the changing width of the motorcycle cylinder in reverse but only one or two of the buildings.

Comment: @AzorAhai: (cue laughter)

Comment: A “bunch” of buildings? Are you sure you’re in the right place?

Comment: I would call it a "head shop".

Comment: @AzorAhai There are 3 buildings with similar shading to the orange curly thingies on the upside-down Darleks...

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to suggest "**stratified**", but a Google search reveals that that term is already used in real estate to mean something completely different.

For architecture, I think the best fit is "**striated**", as in, for example [Strata and Striations in Architecture](https://www.dezeen.com/tag/strata-and-striations/).  A google image search for "striated buildings" also seems to match what you're looking for.

The relevent definition in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/striation) is

> **striation**
>   : a minute groove, scratch, or channel especially when one of a parallel series

The term is most often used to refer to the alternating light and dark bands in striated muscle.